# Is there an equivalent to debirf for CentOS?

Tags: debian, centos

I've been using debirf to create a ram-only image of Debian. Is there an equivalent tool for CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with tmpfs on CentOS-5+ (not sure about CentOS-4)

**tmpfs** *is a special filesystem that does not reside on a physical disk but rather in a portion of your memory. This has the side effect that if you lose power (or reboot) all contents on tmpfs are lost.*

Example:

```
tmpfs                   /tmp                    tmpfs   size=512m       0 0
```

More details could be found here:

http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/TmpOnTmpfs

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt

Comment: Debirf has infrastructure for building a complete Debian install into a ramdisk. It provides templates for rescue mode, kiosk mode, etc. I know that tmpfs can be used for this, but I was hoping CentOS has a similar tool for generating a complete ramdisk.